# Tuning alignment when using simplewick for subscripts

Tags: horizontal-alignment, packages, subscripts

I'm trying to reproduce this equation, which uses [`simplewick`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/simplewick) to connect tensor indices. If it matters, it is *not* a Wick contraction.

[image: equation to reproduce with simplewick]

Here is an MWE that I compile with `latexmk -pdf example.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{simplewick}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \bcontraction[4pt]{K4 = v}{{}_i}{_{jP}v^{PQ}v_{klQ}\sigma}{{}_a}
  \bcontraction[6pt]{K4 = v_{i}}{{}_j}{_{j}v^{PQ}v_{klQ}\sigma_{a}^{k}\sigma}{{}_b}
  K4 = v_{ijP}v^{PQ}v_{klQ}\sigma_{a}^{k}\sigma_{b}^{l}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Now, I think this reproduces it exactly, and in fact it has better alignment under `b` than the example. So, I think it's close enough to have the intent of the contractions understood. But, it's still not perfect, because the line is too far right of the `a` and the `j`.

- Is there any way to fine-tune the alignment of the contractions? In particular, I'm not sure if the two contractions are optimally specified.

I think I'd be allowed to package a modified style file with my source. Note that I cannot switch to `simpler-wick`, since I don't think the journal I'm submitting to allows xelatex and TikZ, which `simpler-wick` requires.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You could ask the journal to use `xelatex or TikZ`. I can compile with pdflatex, but not with latexmk.

Comment: @Bobyandbob I could, but they offer almost no details on their compilation and state "Use additional packages only when they are **required** to support your content", so I think I'd rather deal with my solution than force a switch unless I want to do something that just looks horrific without `simpler-wick`. I also forgot to mention I can't get underbars to work with `simpler-wick`, which I need. I was also under the impression that `latexmk` called `pdflatex` by default...it shouldn't make a difference for my MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I have no idea about this package but I added some positive and negative thin space at likely looking places.*

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{simplewick}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \bcontraction[4pt]{K4 = v}{{}_i}{_{jP}v^{PQ}v_{klQ}\sigma}{{}_a\!}\,
  \bcontraction[6pt]{K4 = v_{i}}{{}_j\!}{\,_{j}v^{PQ}v_{klQ}\sigma_{a}^{k}\sigma}{{}_b}
  K4 = v_{ijP}v^{PQ}v_{klQ}\sigma_{a}^{k}\sigma_{b}^{l}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```