# How do I add underbrackets to express antisymmetrization of a tensor

Tags: math-mode, equations

How can I write the following equation?

[image]

I want to start from

```
\begin{equation}
  R_{\alpha\mu\beta\nu} = \partial_{\alpha\beta}\phi_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation }
```

and add the underbrackets as in the figure I have posted.

Comment: Welcome. Only the formula or also with the brakets?

Comment: Actually, I don't know where to start from to write such term. Is there any package? I have never needed to write such equations

Comment: Apart from the brackets everything can be done with standard LaTeX.  Please try to type everything but the brackets and add it to your question.  That makes the question a lot more specific, i.e. “How do I add underbrackets“ rather than “Please type this for me”.

Comment: I am supposed to know how to write a basic equation in Latex. However, I'll edit my question accordingly to your comment.

Comment: @apt45 `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\mathbf R_{\alpha\mu\beta\nu}=\partial_{\alpha\beta} \phi_{\mu\nu}\]
\end{document}`

Comment: Similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/396820/82917

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution with `pstricks`: I defined the indices as nodes, and linked them with the node connection `\ncbar` with the relevant parameters:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

  \begin{postscript}%
  \everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
  \begin{equation}
        R_{\alpha\mu\beta\nu} = \partial_{\Rnode{a}{\alpha}\Rnode{b}{\beta}}\phi_{\Rnode{m}{\mu}\Rnode{n}{\nu}} 
  \end{equation}
    \psset{linewidth=0.4pt, linearc=0.03, angle=-90, nodesep=2pt}
    \ncbar[arm=1.6mm, nodesepB=0.5pt]{a}{m}
    \ncbar[arm=2.4mm, nodesepA=0.5pt]{b}{n}
  \end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]